# Python selenium get inside a #document

Tags: python, selenium, iframe, scraper

How can I keep looking for elements in a #document:

```
<div>
    <iframe>
        #document
            <html>
               <body>
                   <div>
                        Element I want to find  
                   </div>
               </body>
            </html>
    </iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Do u mean you have to search for this element "Element I want to find " in the document?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think your problem is not with the `a#`document but with `iframe`.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
iframe = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')[0]
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div")
```

Comment: tanks, that worked! And after that if I want to get the text of a span without id, class, or name? What can I do?

Comment: element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span"),   element.get_attribute("innderHTML")

Comment: the actual xpath may not be as simple as "//span", it depends on your actual HTML document layout.