# How to find a page element using Selenium?

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, element

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIPtR.png)

```
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://compass.tinkoff.ru/")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(20)

elem = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[text()="Открыть 
полную карту"]').click()
time.sleep(20)

phone = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//[@automation-id='phone- 
input']")
phone.send_keys("12345678")
time.sleep(20)
```

So i added a photo of html, and need to find the element and add a phone number in an empty field. Whatever i tried (through ID or CLASS_NAME) the element cannot be found/

Comment: Please show the full code and the full error traceback message.

Comment: driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://compass.tinkoff.ru/")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(20)

#открыть полную
elem = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[text()="Открыть полную карту"]').click()
time.sleep(20)

phone = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//[@automation-id='phone-input']")

Comment: It's hard to read code in a comment.  Please edit the question and put the full code and full error message there.

Comment: The error message refers to `//input` in the selector, but that is not in the code.  Are you sure that is the actual code you tried?

Comment: try adding a `time.sleep` before finding the element, element might have been getting loaded at the run-time

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45246280/selenium-drivers-page-source-different-than-browser

Comment: `iframe` `#document` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363643/python-selenium-get-inside-a-document

Answer (score 1):

The element you're looking for is inside an `iframe`

Try this.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")   
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)        
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='app']")))

driver.maximize_window()

# switch to the iframe..
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe"))

# using wait for the element..
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[.='Открыть всю карту']"))).click()

# switch to the main window ...
driver.switch_to.default_content()

phone_input = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@role='textbox']")
phone_input.send_keys("99999999")
```